# Fastest method of sending asynchronous HTTP requests?

Tags: php, http, asynchronous

I currently have a bookmarklet that is used by many people in my department at work. The script takes a list of product IDs or gathers a list from the current page and visits each product detail page and gets various pieces of information. Using queries is not possible as I don't have database access. Anyway, I was thinking of building a fully fledged application for this + other features using either rails or PHP/some other framework. The biggest thing is the ability to send asynchronous HTTP requests as Javascript does.
I found this project: http://code.google.com/p/multirequest/, but haven't looked into it yet. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: PHP is inherently bad at multithreading but CURL supports multiple asynchronous requests. Don't forget to implement caching of information which will remain constant - that way you can avoid the http roundtrip altogether :)

Answer (score 0):

See this library https://code.google.com/p/multirequest/

It allows you to send multiple concurrent requests with CURL from PHP v5+

[An example script](https://code.google.com/p/multirequest/source/browse/trunk/example/index.php) is available which basically boils down to...

- Define callback methods for when each request completes
- Define what each request will look like (headers, etc)
- Push each url to the `MultiRequest_Handler` class
- Start the `MultiRequest_Handler`

Answer (score 0):

At the most basic level, you can use [multi curl in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php). I've tested up to 150 simultaneous requests. You'd want to set a timeout to make sure a single request doesn't stall the whole process. It's not asynchronous, it's simultaneous, but it's quick.